# Getting an 11000 error when handling this POST request

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman, api-design

When I use Chrome's Postman and do a POST with a new name/username/password, it returns the 11000 error (or at least it does what I told it to int he event of an 11000 error).

Here is the code that handles the error, but maybe not the code that causes it. I'm following code from a book, and there's a lot of it, so let me know what else would be necessary to diagnose the problem. Here is just a route.

```
apiRouter.route('/users')
    .post(function(req, res) {

      var user = new User();

      user.name = req.body.name;
      user.username = req.body.username;
      user.password = req.body.password;

      user.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            if(err.code == 11000) {
              return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists.' });
            } else {
                return res.send(err);
            }
        }

        res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    });
})
```

Comment: does it work not using Postman?
also, you may want to print out (maybe to log or something) the data received from your request (body.name / body.username / body.password) - maybe your request didn't go through? (is it possible that the body is empty and you are inserting blank values?)

do you have existing values stored in your DB?

Comment: please post your response as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to log each of the values as being submitted. And they are definitely not duplicates of existing data.

Comment: Did you try logging the `err` object? Maybe it has some insights. I'm fairly certain MongoDB wouldn't throw an 11000 if there weren't any duplicates. Maybe also post your `user.save` method.